# Troubles with synchronization between desktop and mobile (android) outlook app

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, android, microsoft-outlook-365

I have **Outlook from Office365** on my PC (**Windows 10**), and **Outlook** app on my mobile phone (**Android**). Both are utilized to read my e-mails from my business account. It is working on both platform but **each app use it's own sent/trash localizations**. On my PC I have:

- Sent Items
- Deleted Items

Why on my mobile it looks as follows:

- Sent
- Trash

It is really uncomfortable as for example when I send something from my phone, it is placed in different folder than from my PC. It splits my correspondence between two places. What's more, for example draft folder is correctly recognized in both platforms, so I have it in one place. What can I do to fix the problem? I don't care which options will win, the exact name of folder is not relevant for me. I just want to have it in one places. I was trying to remove and add again my account to the Outlook365 but it still recognize it the same way, using it's own folders instead of the default. **It looks like the mobile version use "native" folders of my e-mail, while PC version created its own.** I would be grateful for any advices how to solve it.

Comment: Are you aware that Outlook Android app is not a IMAP client (no direct communication between app an IMAP server)? Instead it sens your IMAP credentials to a Microsoft cloud server which logs into your IMAP folder and manages communication between app and IMAP server (some would call this a Man-in-the-Middle).

Comment: To be honest - it is my business e-mail, so I can accept it. But I could also use build in e-mail on my phone. Anything which will let me synchronize with desktop Outlook - with this I'm bound because of some compatibility. But my build in app also use Sent/Tresh pathes, with no possibility to change. So I would need to force desktop Outlook first to correctly recognize the path instead of creating it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Login to the webmail first to know what the server uses. Send email from there and see where it goes. Once you know what is correct, you can rule out which one of your devices is doing it wrong and troubleshoot that specific client.

Office365 webmail can be accessed through https://outlook.office365.com.

You'll find out that Sent Items and Deleted Items are correct, and that your mobile phone is doing it wrong.

Comment: It's not Office365 webmail, it's my organization IMAP/SMTP server. And Send/Trash are native names in my case. Desktop version creates it's own. I can rename them to whatever I want. So I can change to Sent Items and Deleted Items, but this will break compatibility with phone. So what to do now?

Comment: You mentioned Outlook365, that is the email service that comes with Office365. The office suite is called Office or MS Outlook 2016, Outlook 2019 etc... But this minor change keeps the answer to be the same. find out how to log into webmail, perform the steps and you will know which client is messing things up. Also, if one client connects through Exchange, and the other through IMAP, things like this can happen.

Comment: I edited OP, to make it more clear. I have Outlook from Office365, it was just shortcut. Under the webmail, the correct path is /Sent and /Trash, so the mobile version recognizes it correctly, but PC version creates Sent Items and Deleted Items, instead of use the default path. So what should I check/change next?

Answer (score 0):

Before going further, please make sure you have both used IMAP type when adding your email accounts to your desktop and mobile.

As I know, IMAP accounts should be able to sync their emails with their mail server. So, can you see the "Sent Items" and "Deleted Items" folders on your web mail?

Personally I think, the best way to resolve this issue is to check all the folders on your web mail, back up your messages and remove those folders you do not want. Then try creating and using a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile and re-add your email account freshly to see if the issue has any difference.

Comment: Yes, desktop Outlook created this folders also on the server, so I can see it from the webmail. I tried to re-add the account, as I mentioned in the OP - desktop version will just create "Sent Items" and "Deleted Items" once again, and ignore default path.

Comment: For IMAP email accounts in Outlook desktop client, maybe you could try add the Root folder in your account settings to see if the issue has any difference.

Comment: Ok, how to check root folder name?

Comment: You could configure your root folder with the steps in this article: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/619

Comment: This article is very general. What exactly to type as the root? It's not Gmail.

Comment: Usually, I would set Inbox as the root folder path. By the way, have you checked which IMAP account folders appear in your Outlook? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-which-imap-account-folders-appear-in-outlook-32103602-a568-4499-9d25-54fe236aee6a